# Type mismatch Eclipse for jsoup

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to java, and want to use the jsoup java library. I downloaded the jar file, and included it in my project. Next, I want to run a simple example, on their [page](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-document-from-string)

```
String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
  + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

On second line I get error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.jsoup.nodes.Document to 
 javax.swing.text.Document
```

And offers:

> Add 'cast' to document or change type (org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc =
>   Jsoup.parse(html);)

What is the problem? Have I forgotten to do something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your imports at the top of your program, most surely you're importing `javax.swing.text.Document` when you want to import `org.jsoup.nodes.Document`

Comment: javax.swing.text.Document was by default. I changed to org.jsoup.nodes.Document. Will these changes affect my application in some wrong way?

Comment: Tigran: The short answer is that this change will allow your application to compile. There are multiple classes named `Document` available to your program, and you need to be sure that you're using the correct one. It will not have any bad effects on your application.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of `doc` to the appropriate type offered by Eclipse - although the two `Document` types have the same name, they are not the same.